# How can you reset the colors for Windows PowerShell if they become corrupted after running a program?

Tags: node.js, powershell, colors

I am starting to use PowerShell for a Windows project using node.js.  When running many programs (including node, supervisor and npm) from the Powershell commmand line, my PowerShell background and foreground colors start to change from the default Powershell colors.  How can I maintain a consistent look within PowerShell so I can easily read the results of running commands?

Comment: Wow, 3 good answers.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I have this problem with MSBuild especially when I ctrl+C a build.  This is what I put in my profile.ps1 file:

```
$OrigBgColor = $host.ui.rawui.BackgroundColor
$OrigFgColor = $host.ui.rawui.ForegroundColor

# MSBUILD has a nasty habit of leaving the foreground color red
# if you Ctrl+C while it is outputting errors.
function Reset-Colors {
    $host.ui.rawui.BackgroundColor = $OrigBgColor
    $host.ui.rawui.ForegroundColor = $OrigFgColor
}
```

Then I just invoke Reset-Colors when MSBuild has messed them up.

Answer (score 71):

As a one-time operation just run this:

```
> [Console]::ResetColor()
```

[From the docs:](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.resetcolor%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)  (emphasis added)

> The foreground and background colors are **restored to the colors that existed when the current process began**.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. No profile setup necessary.

Comment: It would be a good accepted answer except that it doesn't work for me, and actually after manually fixing the problem by copying the `$host.ui.rawui` values from another window this makes the problem return.

Answer (score 13):

First create a profile in PowerShell if you do not have one already:

```
test-path $profile
new-item -path $profile -itemtype file -force
notepad $profile
```

Second, put this code in the file:

```
function prompt {
  [Console]::ResetColor()
}
```

Third, check if PowerShell will allow you to run scripts.

```
Get-ExecutionPolicy
```

If this says Restricted then run the following AS Administrator (please be sure you understand the security implications):

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned
```

Open up a new PowerShell prompt and you should be able run node or other commands without any color issues.

Comment: Commenting to add, if you use posh-git there's a chance you're using the default profile, which defines a `prompt` function, so make sure you add `[Console]::ResetColor()` to that function otherwise you'll overwrite it, and loose all that posh-git niceness.

Answer (score 1):

I fix the color issue by running the following commands:

```
cmd
color 07
exit
```

What these commands do is to run cmd in PowerShell, run `color 07` to fix the color, and exit from cmd to revert to PowerShell.

Comment: It doesnt' reset the color, it sets the color to white on black. 
Moreover, it could be just: "cmd /c color 07"